# c# linq discrad InsertOnSubmit

Tags: c#, linq, submitchanges

i have a problem while using SubmitChanges() and InsertOnSubmit(),
if the SubmitChanges fail and raise an exception the change set remains filled with the object that have a conflict in the db (e.g. the primary key already exists). the problem is that if i re-execute the piece of code that insert the element in the database   the SubmitChanges fail because the object with the wrong primary key is in the change set.
The question is how to delete the first obj from the change set?

```
private void bInsInserisci_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Prodotto tmp = new Prodotto();
        try {
            tmp.idProdotto = InsProdCodProd.Text;
            tmp.tempo = Int32.Parse(InsProdTemp.Text);
            tmp.note = InsProdNote.Text;
            prodotti.InsertOnSubmit(tmp);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch {
            System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use Replace instead of Insert.

Comment: Side note - use only English in your variable and method names. You will thank me later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not discard the context? Take a look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dinesh.kulkarni/2008/04/28/lifetime-of-a-linq-to-sql-datacontext/) article concerning the lifetime of a L2S datacontext. " DataContext could be used after SubmitChanges() but one has to be careful."